# Changing citations in bibtex with apacite

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, apacite

When using the `apacite` package, the citations that have no date entry are printed as:

> (xxx, n.d.)

How do I change it to:

> (xxx, e.d.)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) What `\bibliographystyle` are you using?

Comment: \usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nosectionbib]{apacite}

Comment: See my updated answer. The original didn't work properly.

Answer (score 2):

The replacement text in `apacite` in case there is no date is stored in the `\bibnodate` macro. The default is `n.d.\hbox{}`.

To change it, just add the following to your preamble:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\bibnodate}{e.d.\hbox{}}
```